# Inconsistent display of post scores on "known good" audits in the Low Quality review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits, low-quality-posts

When an *answer* is presented as an "known good" audit in the Low Quality review queue, <s>its score is shown as 0. The real (positive) score is revealed only after user's decision on the audit.</s> its real score is shown, just as for question audits. I was hallucinating.

But when a *question* is a "known good" audit in the same queue, its real score (5 or higher) is shown. This makes such audits obvious without even looking at the post, especially because one can't flag upvoted questions as either VLQ or NAA.  Example:

[image]

I know the audits aren't meant to be super-hard, but I don't see the logic of treating questions differently from answers here.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought that you are talking about the question that is shown a bit faded below the answer in the review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither question nor answer audits of both known good and bad varieties had their score tampered with in the low quality queue. After sites build rev `2015.1.6.2145` they will.